# Need intuition on the meaning of a uniqueness statement

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

These statements are commonly used to prove Existence and Uniqueness.

1. $\exists x (P(x) \land \forall y (P(y) \rightarrow y=x)$
2. $\exists x P(x) \land \forall y \forall z ((P(y) \land P(z)) \rightarrow y=z)$

I understand how the first part of the statements show existence. But i dont know how to interpret the second parts that show uniqueness. What do they tell us about uniqueness? How does y=x and y=z imply uniqueness?

Answer (score 1):

In the first case the uniqueness is implied by the fact that if it exists an y such that $P(y)$ holds, then this $y$ is actually $x$, which means that only $x$ satisfies $P(x)$. Remember that "x=y" means that $x$ and $y$ are the same thing. If you think about an example it should be clear: assume $P(x)\equiv x<1$. Then, if we work inside $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$, clearly $\exists\, ! \ x \in \mathbb{N} \ | P(x)$. Surely it exists such $x$, and it is $0$. And for each $y\in \mathbb{N}$ either $y=0$ or $P(y)$ does not hold.

In the second case you are saying that $\exists x P(x)$, and that's the existence. Than, you are saying that for each $y,z$ if it holds both $P(y)$ and $P(z)$ then $y=z$ and, since the "$=$" is transitive, all the elements for which $P$ holds are equal, which means that there is only one element which satisfies $P$

Answer (score 1):

Let's focus on number one first.

It should translate to "there is only one $x$ such that $P(x)$".

We separate this into two pieces:

1. there is at least one $x$ such that $P(x)$
2. there is at most one $x$ such that $P(x)$

That there is one or more $x$'s such that $P(x)$ is to say $\exists x.\ P(x)$.

That there is no more than one $x$ such that $P(x)$ is to say that $\forall y.\ P(y)\rightarrow y=x$. Any object which satisfies $P$ is $x$. (So $x$ is the only object which satisfies $P$.)

All in all, if there's at most 1 and at least 1, then there must be exactly 1.

---

Now number two.

Notice that if you choose $z:=x$ in $\forall y,z.\ P(y) \land P(z) \rightarrow y = z$ you get
$$\forall y.\ P(y) \land P(x) \rightarrow y = x$$

but $P(x)$ is satisfied by hypothesis, so it's trivial information and you can forget it. Then you get
$$\forall y.\ P(y) \rightarrow y = x$$

which is what you had in number one.